# Staging a component for testing

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, aurelia, jspm

Executing the app and loading views with `@useview('resources/panels/data-table-panel.html')` works, but running a component test fails. Caused by 404 html-file not found.

By changing the path to `@useview('src/resources/panels/data-table-panel.html')` the component can be staged, which the leads to a 404 if the app gets started later by serving it with gulp.

[image: Custom Component]

[image: Staging the component]

[image: File Tree]

[image: Karma Conf]

Does anybody have an idea how to workaround this problem?
thx

Comment: It seems you already got an answer to this somewhere in Discourse? If so, can you help link it here. For clarity, are you using the built in bundler or Webpack?

Comment: no i got no feedback at all. i am not using webpack. i use this skeleton : https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried the jspm skeleton. It's quite outdated, I recommend you to create a new project with latest aurelia-cli, then migrate source and test over.

Speaking about the code itself, you can switch the absolute path to relative path:

```js
@useview('../path/to/resources/panels/data-table-panel.html')
```

This should work. Relative path bypasses karma config on those absolute module resolution.

---

I don't quite understand why the karma.config has following:

```
paths: {
          "*": "*",
          "src/*": "src/*",
```

I thought it probably should be

```
paths: {
          "*": "src/*",
```

Then you have to remove all `src/` prefix, like `.withResources('resources/...')`.